# Fastest and Best Performance in Select Views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-view

This is My View:

```
CREATE VIEW [Products].[VProductFull] AS 
SELECT
    [Pr].[Id],
    [Pr].[Title],
    [Pr].[IsScanAllowed],
    [Pr].[Category_Id],
    [Cat].[Title] AS [Category],
    [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id],
    [Mc].[Title] AS [MajorCategory]
FROM [Products].[Product] AS [Pr]
INNER JOIN [Products].[Category] AS [Cat] ON [Pr].[Category_Id] = [Cat].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Products].[MajorCategory] AS [Mc] ON [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] = [Mc].[Id];
GO
```

And I need an SP To get `VProductFull` By `MajorCategoryId` there are 2 SPs, first one select use joins like create view and second one use own view:

```
-- SP#1
CREATE PROCEDURE [Products].[GetFullProductByMajorCategory](
@MajorCategoryid            [bigint]
)
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION [FullProductByMajor]
    SELECT
        [Pr].[Id],
        [Pr].[Title],
        [Pr].[IsScanAllowed],
        [Pr].[Category_Id],
        [Cat].[Title] AS [Category],
        [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id],
        [Mc].[Title] AS [MajorCategory]
    FROM [Products].[Product] AS [Pr]
    INNER JOIN [Products].[Category] AS [Cat] ON [Pr].[Category_Id] = [Cat].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [Products].[MajorCategory] AS [Mc] ON [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] = [Mc].[Id]
    WHERE [Mc].[Id] = @MajorCategoryid;
COMMIT TRANSACTION [FullProductByMajor]
END
GO
```

And

```
-- SP#2
CREATE PROCEDURE [Products].[GetFullProductByMajorCategory](
@MajorCategoryid            [bigint]
)
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION [FullProductByMajor]
    SELECT 
            [VPF].[Id],
            [VPF].[Title],
            [VPF].[IsScanAllowed],
            [VPF].[Category_Id],
            [VPF].[Category],
            [VPF].[MajorCategory_Id],
            [VPF].[MajorCategory] 
    FROM [Products].[VProductFull] AS [VPF]
    WHERE [VPF].[MajorCategory_Id] = @MajorCategoryid;
COMMIT TRANSACTION [FullProductByMajor]
END
GO
```

Which of the above SPs return faster and have better performance? and why? And is there another way to get `VProductFull` by `MajorCategoryId` faster with better performance rather than above SPs?

Comment: why are you using `Transactions` for select.

Comment: @Furqan Yes, There is no need to use `Transactions` This is just my default type to create procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have the same execution times and there will be no difference between them. At runtime the view will just be expanded to its underlying query. You can see this for yourself by looking at the query plans for both versions.

To optimize, you need to make `VProductFull` an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). Meaning a materialized view. Then, when selecting from it use the [`NOEXPAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint. If you want to extend your knowledge about indexed views, you can read more [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx).

If you do not want to use an indexed view, then use a non-indexed view but make sure you create two *non-clustered indexes* on the two tables: on `[Pr].[Category_Id]` and on `[Cat].[MajorCategory_Id]`.

You need these indexes in order to avoid clustered index scans, and use the much faster index seek plan operators.

For the first index you should include the following columns in the index (as included columns, not index columns): `[Title]`, `[IsScanAllowed]`, `[Id]`. For the second index you should include column `[Cat].[Title]`.

I think you can experiment with both and then compare the query plans as well as execution times (with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`.

My bet is that the indexed view will be faster but, if you have large base tables, the indexed view will have an impact on inserts/updates in the base tables. So you may want a trade-off in order to get balanced performance in all situations.

---

For reference, and for whoever will read this question, please post the current execution plans and times and the ones after you apply each modification. That's if this is not too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using `Transactions` in `Select` Statements?
2. Have you considered using `SQL Profiler`? That means you can check the `Reads` and `Duration` for a particular Query.
3. Do you have `Indexes` on the column being used in the `Where` clause?
4. The above mentioned `View` should be `Indexed View`.

---

Try below Query directly in your `Stored Proc` and compare the `Reads` and `Duration` in `SQL Profiler`

```
Select 
K.[MajorCategory],
[Pr].[Id],
[Pr].[Title],
[Pr].[IsScanAllowed],
[Pr].[Category_Id],
[Cat].[Title] AS [Category],
[Cat].[MajorCategory_Id],
From
(
    Select [Title] AS [MajorCategory], [Id]
    From [Products].[MajorCategory]
    WHERE [Id] = @MajorCategoryid;
)K
INNER JOIN [Products].[Category] AS [Cat] ON [Cat].[MajorCategory_Id] = K.[Id]
INNER JOIN [Products].[Product] AS [Pr] ON [Pr].[Category_Id] = [Cat].[Id]
```

In this suggestion, as per my understanding, the `Table Scan` will not take place for all `Matching records` on the basis of `Category` and `Product` Table(**This is as per the query in the `View`**). It will instead depends upon merely the single record of `MajorCategory` Table.(**This is as per my suggestion**)

Comment: You can see from the create statement that the view is not schemabound, therefore it can't be indexed. SQL Profiler is not useful in this poarticular situation, as you already have the queries you're interested in. A best practice in queries performance analysis is to start by analyzing the query plans. I realize that knowing all plan operators and relations between them takes some time getting used to, but the benefits outweigh the initial effort.